# Rails integration test failing on ajax get request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, integration-testing, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a page that is rendering an edit comment form.  **Everything works in the browser as intended**.  Now trying to write an integration test for it and it is failing with a 422 status. Looking thru the test logs it the error is: `"ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest:  Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript....`

Not sure why i'm getting this error. I'm using `xhr: true, format: :js` All of my other post/patch ajax tests are working as intended.

**comments_test.rb:**

```
require 'test_helper'
class CommentsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @user  = users(:user1)
    @post   = posts(:post1)
    @comments = @post.comments
  end

  test "should get edit with ajax" do
    log_in_as @user
    get edit_comment_path(@comments.first), xhr: true, format: :js
    assert_response 304
  end
end
```

**routes:**

```
     user_post_comments POST   /:user_id/:post_id/comments(.:format)     posts/comments#create
  new_user_post_comment GET    /:user_id/:post_id/comments/new(.:format) posts/comments#new
           edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)              posts/comments#edit
                comment PATCH  /comments/:id(.:format)                   posts/comments#update
                        PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)                   posts/comments#update
                        DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)                   posts/comments#destroy
```

**comments_controller.rb:**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_comment, only:[:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authorize_user, only:[:edit, :update, :destroy]

  .
  .
  .
  def edit
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {  render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: @comment.commentable} }
      format.js
    end
  end
  .
  .
end
```

**edit.js.erb:**

```
$("#comment_<%= @comment.hashid %>").hide();
$("#comment_<%= @comment.hashid %>").after('<%= j (render partial: "form", locals: { comment: @comment}) %>');
```

Note: everything works fine using the html format. Seems to be an issue with csrf, but from what i understand `xhr: true, format: :js` should resolve that issue, and all of my other ajax tests work fine.  Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected I change my test to:

```
xhr :get, edit_comment_path(@comments.first), format: :js
assert_response :success
```

No idea why it doesn't work with the `xhr: true` syntax when it works for other methods such as post/patch/delete..   *shrug.*